# Unable to add appointments to scheduler

Tags: c#, datatable, devexpress

I am trying to add appointments fetched from the database. I fetch them "manually". I store them in a datatable called dt. The data is present in the datatable.

```
foreach (Resource r in schedulerStorage1.Resources.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Caption + " - " + r.Id);
}

Appointment app;
foreach (DataRow dr in result.DataTable_Result.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr[0] + " - " + dr[1] + " - " + dr[2]);

    app = schedulerControl1.Storage.CreateAppointment(AppointmentType.Normal);
    app.ResourceId = dr[0];
    app.Start = DateTime.Parse(dr[1].ToString());
    app.End = DateTime.Parse(dr[2].ToString());

    schedulerControl1.Storage.Appointments.Add(app);
}
```

**Output of the Console.WriteLines:**

Room1 - 1

Room2 - 2

1 - 16/01/2013 8:00:00 AM - 16/01/2013 8:05:00 AM

1 - 16/01/2013 9:00:00 AM - 16/01/2013 9:05:00 AM

2 - 16/01/2013 8:00:00 AM - 16/01/2013 8:30:00 AM

Any ideas about why the appointments are not added ?

Comment: Are you having culture formatting issues? The `Start` and `End` properties are a string, therefore they expect a specific formatting.

Comment: Please rewrite your `Console.ReadLine` line so that we can see seperators to identify the 3 datarow columns. Possibly you have no valid values as input.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because it worked earlier without the formatting. I will try to set the format. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Added "-" to the console.writeline. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: yes thank you. I wanted to be sure that 2 date values were parsed for the `Start` and `End` string.

Comment: Appointments are present in the schedulerControl1.Storage.Appointments.Items. But they don't show up on the scheduler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I managed to find out the source of the problem.

dr[0] is the resource id.

When I added a resource I wrote:

```
            r = new Resource(dr[0], dr[1].ToString());
```

When I added an appointment I wrote:

```
            app.ResourceId = dr[0];
```

The following will fix the appointments not showing up.

```
            r = new Resource(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString());
            app.ResourceId = dr[0].ToString();
```

Now everything works perfectly.
Thank you Aphelion for your help. :D